# Why does not compile? Where is the error?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm starting to use the Euclide package. I want to draw a five-sided regular polygons.Why does not compile? Where is the error?

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} 
\tkzDefPoint(5,0){A}
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\foreach \i in {0,...4,}{
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation = center O angle 72+72*\i](A) \tkzGetPoint{a\i}
}
\tkzDrawPolygon[color=red!50!Gold,ultra thick]{a0,a1,a2,a3,a4}
\tkzDrawPoint[color=red!50!Gold,size=10]{a0,a1,a2,a4}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One error is `\foreach \i in {0,...4} {...`, there's an `,` missing before the `4`

Comment: Christian Hupfer, I corrected. But, still doesn't compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a list of mistakes:

1. You mistyped the `\foreach` values, where `0,...4,` is of course wrong and should be replaced with `0,...,4`.
2. The commands `\tkzDrawPolygon` and `\tkzDrawPoint` require regular brackets, and not curly brackets.
3. When a command like `\tkzDrawPoint` lists more than one coordinate, the command becomes "pluralized", so you have `\tkzDrawPoints`.
4. The color `Gold` is undefined, so you need to add `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} 
\tkzDefPoint(5,0){A}

\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)

\foreach \i in {0,...,4}{%
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center O angle 72+72*\i](A) \tkzGetPoint{a\i}
}
\tkzDrawPolygon[color=red!50!Gold,ultra thick](a0,a1,a2,a3,a4)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=red!50!Gold,size=10](a0,a1,a2,a4)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```